# Is there such a thing as a proper `bit` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, types, boolean, bit

I know that there is a [Boolean object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) in JavaScript, but I'm wondering if there is a way to access the metal, the raw single `bit` that lives at the heart of this Boolean object.

Comment: What would you need to access this for?

Comment: Most languages and Frameworks don't use a "bit" for boolean. .NET uses a byte, C++ uses a few, but on the Microsoft stack usually a 32-bit integer; etc.

Comment: vcsjones - Yeah, I know.  Probably I should have phrased the question differently.  What I am looking for is a primitive bit - I wanted to avoid answers that suggested that I simply use a boolean.

Comment: @alex - I am a bit of a numerical methods junkie, and I'm interested in playing around with arbitrary-precision or just N-precision numbers in js.  Searching around hasn't revealed me any primitive data-types, like byte or bit, which would allow me to build up such N-precision numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any `bit` type in javascript. If you're worried about conserving space and need to store a lot of bits, you could probably use `int`s and [Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) in conjunction. You'd be manipulating the individual bits within each int (so 32 on most systems)

Comment: Dylan, thanks.  How can I construct a primitive int object?  I'm probably going to do exactly what you suggest here.  Ideally I'd use `byte`s instead of `bit`s, but I'm pretty happy to use `int`s in this case.  I'll let you know how it goes.  I'd still be curious to know if there is a primitive `bit` data-type, but I'm going to accept this answer for now.

Comment: I thought you could restrict the types of vars in javascript, but searching around quickly seems to say otherwise. But if you say something like `var i=0` then `i` will be an `int` because that's what 0 is. I might recommend writing a class to manage the individual bits and wrap that `i` so that it doesn't get inadvertently changed into a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access it, but you can assume `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I probably should have mentioned in my post, I want to do some arbitrary-presicion stuff, so I'm looking for something with a lower memory footprint than a boolean if possible.